# issue in if condition in php

Tags: php, html

I'm building a project with php and html
and i want to make a function have some if conditions and another tings.

there is three conditions one of them not working and i'm surely it's true condition and tried to echo the expression of it and it's true, it returns noting like `echo '';`

I've made a comment next to the elseif which have the issue.

Notice: All the other conditions is good and working.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
require_once '../../router.php';
require_once '../../'.router('function', 'mini');
require_once '../../'.router('mysql', 'db');
function groups_checker()
{
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
        if(isset($_GET['grade']))
        {
            global $db;
            $get_groups_select_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE g_grade = '".$_GET['grade']."' ORDER BY `g_max_num` DESC"); // Checking groups existence.
            if(mysqli_num_rows($get_groups_select_query) > 0)
            {
                $get_groups_select_query_fetch = $get_groups_select_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Fetching data after true existence.
                ?>
                <h3>We've found <?= mysqli_num_rows($get_groups_select_query) > 1 ? mysqli_num_rows($get_groups_select_query).' groups ' : ' just a group ' ?> exist, take a look if appropriate. Or <a href="#">Create one?</a></h3>
                <table width="100%" border="1" class="managing_brdr">
                    <tr class="titles_manage_group_main">
                        <td rowspan="2">Group Symbol</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Group name</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Group grade</td>
                        <td colspan="4">Appointments</td>
                        <td rowspan="2">Remaining places</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="titles_manage_group_main">
                        <td>First day</td>    
                        <td>Time</td>    
                        <td>Second day</td>    
                        <td>Time</td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_symbol']; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_name']; ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade']; ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_fst_day']; ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= dateConverter($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_fst_d_time']); ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_sec_day']; ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering"><?= dateConverter($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_sec_d_time']); ?></td>
                        <td class="td_centering">
                        <?php
                        if(empty($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']))
                        {
                            ?>
                            It's unlimited. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add</a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) > intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']))
                        {
                            if(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) == 1)
                            {
                                ?>
                                Just 1 place left. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add<a>
                                <?php
                            }
                            elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) == intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number'])) // **the issue here.**
                            {
                                ?>
                                It's Full. <a href="">Make an exception</a>
                                <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) . ' places left. <a href="'.'../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'].'">Add<a>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>    
                <table>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                if(!empty($_GET['grade']))
                {
                    alerts('error', 'We didn\'t find any group in '.strtolower($_GET['grade']).', <a href="#">Create one?</a>');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
groups_checker();
?>
```

Comment: Do you use xdebug? what IDE are you using?

Comment: `var_dump($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']);` and `var_dump($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']);`, what do you get?

Comment: @Qirel
I get int(10) int(10). and i didn't use xdebug.

Comment: You are not echoing your href's, i.e. `href="<?= '../../' . router('sections', 'students') . '?action=new_student&steps=second&grade=' . $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>"` should be `href="<?= echo '../../' . router('sections', 'students') . '?action=new_student&steps=second&grade=' . $get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>"`

Comment: @lovelace
Dude, <?= 'Hello world' ?> equals <? echo 'Hello world' ?>

Comment: @ameer - short tags... <?= 'Hello world'; ?> != <?php 'Hello world'; ?>, hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem `elseif` is inside of another, contradictory, `elseif`. You have:

```
if(empty($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']))
{
    ?>
    It's unlimited. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add</a>
    <?php
}
elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) > intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']))
{
    if(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) == 1)
    {
        ?>
        Just 1 place left. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add<a>
        <?php
    }
    elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) == intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number'])) // **the issue here.**
    {
        ?>
        It's Full. <a href="">Make an exception</a>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        echo intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) . ' places left. <a href="'.'../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'].'">Add<a>';
    }
}
```

What I think you want is:

```
if(empty($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']))
{
    ?>
    It's unlimited. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add</a>
    <?php
}
elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) == 1)
{
    ?>
    Just 1 place left. <a href="<?= '../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'] ?>">Add<a>
    <?php
}
elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) == intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number'])) // **the issue here.**
{
    ?>
    It's Full. <a href="">Make an exception</a>
    <?php
}
elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) > intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']))
{
    echo intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) - intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']) . ' places left. <a href="'.'../../'.router('sections', 'students').'?action=new_student&steps=second&grade='.$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_grade'].'">Add<a>';
}
```

Comment: elseif(intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num']) > intval($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number']))

Comment: I think i will add it to the two else if condition

Comment: Oops, right. Edited my answer, adding this condition on the last bit.

Answer (score -1):

Use (int) in place of (intval) where the issue is.

Comment: Nothing changed, the same problem.

Comment: 1. Are you storing the numbers as characters in database ? In that case use "===" instead of "==" where the error is .

2. Also check if g_student_number is a correct field or not .

Comment: cause of that i used intval to make the two vars integers, that's mean i will use ==

Comment: Since the values are string , don't use intval , instead use === , means

elseif($get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_max_num'] ===$get_groups_select_query_fetch['g_student_number'])